# How can I cancel my pass or shoot in FIFA 12?

Tags: fifa-12

I want to cancel my pass/shoot or cross in FIFA.  How can I do that? I'm playing on the XBox 360.

Comment: Have you tried R2 + L2. I don't have Fifa 12, but that's what it was in Fifa 11.

Comment: Hard reset the XBox before you let go of shoot... shot will never be taken. Just one option ;)

Comment: If you have a look on the Fifa controls and various other menus on the MAIN menu screen, im sure ive seen something explaining how to cancel passes, crosses etc.

Answer (score 5):

Just press RT + LT. You can Cancel Pass/Shot this way.

Answer (score 4):

To do a "fake" shot on xbox360: Press B and then A in quick succession.

Here's a list of skill moves if you don't mind "spoilers": http://www.fifaencyclopedia.com/fifa-12-skill-moves.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I know fake shot but I want to cancel my shot I don't want fake

Comment: Oh. Ok. Well, I'm not sure that you can. This was really the only thing I could find on it to be honest. Hopefully someone will come and clarify! :).

Comment: I am quite sure that faking it is the only way to cancel.

Answer (score 3):

When you press LT and RT at the same time, you cancel any action that you executed with your controller but hasn't been executed by the game yet.

For example, if you press A but your player delays before actually passing it, in that interim you can press LT+RT and cancel the pass.

Hope this helps!